# Do we need to install kubectl and docker separately in local system to use terraform kubernetes provider?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, terraform, provider

I am new to terraform. If I use a terraform kubernetes or docker provider, does my local system needs to have kubectl, Docker installed as a prerequisite? Or does the terraform provider only take care of downloading the needed software and the user doesn't need to install it separately?

Comment: I would expect the kubernetes provider to use the go API directly instead of relying on kubectl, but the `helm` and `docker` providers definitely need the external binary.

Comment: Yes the Kubernetes provider uses the Go bindings to the REST API similarly to how `kubectl` is a CLI that also uses the Go bindings to the REST API, and therefore the provider does not need `kubectl` since it is one layer fewer than `kubectl`.